# Sum frequency of one column using command line

Tags: awk, command, frequency

I need to summarize the frequency of one column in a large-tab=separated file.

An example is:

```
abbot   achievement 1
abbot   acknowledge 2
abbot   acknowledge 2
abbot   acknowledge 3
abbot   acquaintance    1
abbot   acquire 2
abbot   acquisition 2
abbot   acre    1
abbot   acre    4
abbot   act 1
abbot   act 4
abbot   act 3
abbot   act 8
abbot   act 5
abbot   act 7
abbot   act 8
abbot   action  2
abbot   active  4
```

I want to sum the frequency of those Columns 1 & 2 that are identical for the final result:

```
abbot   achievement 1
abbot   acknowledge 7
abbot   acquaintance    1
abbot   acquire 2
abbot   acquisition 2
abbot   acre    5
abbot   act 36
abbot   action  2
abbot   active  4
```

I have asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920734/command-line-to-sum-frequency-in-concatenated-file/18920844#18920844): 
and used the following command: 
$ sort input.txt | uniq -c  | awk ' {  print $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $1*$4 } '`

but this does not solve the problem because for instance the sort function will only sum up all three columns that are identical producing a result that adds a new column one with the summed frequency from all three columns.

Can anyone suggest a modification to this command that will produce my desired result?
Or perhaps suggest a better path to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` and sum in array

```
awk '{ a[$1 FS $2]+=$3 } END {for (i in a) print i,a[i] }' file
abbot active 4
abbot action 2
abbot achievement 1
abbot acre 5
abbot acquire 2
abbot acknowledge 7
abbot acquisition 2
abbot act 36
abbot acquaintance 1
```

Comment: Yes, this does work, however, it changes the tabs between each column to spaces. Is it possible to modify this print to keep the tab spaces between columns, or does it need to be done after?

Comment: Change `FS` to `"\t"` and you get tab between `abbot` and next field.  To get tab every where add `OFS="\t"` like this: `awk '{ a[$1 "\t" $2]+=$3 } END {for (i in a) print i,a[i] }' OFS="\t"`